# Solving for $x$ in $A=B\cdot \cos(x)+C\cdot \sin(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I´m working on a little paper, and I want to know if it´s possible in any way to solve this:

$$A=B\cdot \cos(x)+C\cdot \sin(x)$$

$A$, $B$ and $C$ are known. I need a way to get the $x$ without using a computer. If not, how do I make it to work on excel? I've tried SOLVER, but it doesn't work...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is "sen" supposed to be $\sin$? See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). Instead of Excel, I suggest any computer algebra system such as Wolfram Alpha or Sage or...

Comment: Is 'sen' sine or secant? (in either case, the answer is yes, however)

Comment: The abbreviation sen stands for sine in Spanish.  Please see https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seno_(trigonometr%C3%ADa)

Answer (score 4):

Here is the outline of an answer.

Divide both sides by $\sqrt{B^2 + C^2}$, so that it becomes
$$A' = B' \cos X + C' \sin X,$$
where $B'^2 + C'^2 = 1$. Since $(C',B')$ is a point of the unit circle, there is some angle $\alpha$ for which $\cos \alpha = C'$ and $\sin \alpha = B'$. Now rewrite your equation as
$$A' = \sin \alpha \cos X + \cos \alpha \sin X = \sin (X + \alpha).$$
Now your equation is easy to solve.

(An alternative is to write $t = \tan X/2$ and express the right hand side in terms of $t$.)

Comment: One way to find such an angle $\alpha$ is to take $\alpha = \arctan\frac{B'}{C'}.$

Comment: @DavidK That doesn't work if $C' < 0$. Then you have to add $180^{\circ}$. Another special case is $C' = 0$.

Comment: Good point, really you should use $\text{atan2}(B',C')$ (two-parameter arc tangent with range $-\pi$ to $\pi$) if $C'\neq 0$. Of course if $C'=0$ none of these tricks are necessary: just take $x=\pm\arccos(A'/B').$

Answer (score 3):

You can write $A=B\cos (X)+ C\sqrt{1-\cos^2 (X)}$, $(A-B\cos(X))^2=C^2(1-\cos^2(X))$, which is quadratic in $\cos (X)$  As we have squared, we may have introduced a spurious solution.